# Comma usage and the phrase type

Tags: commas, prepositional-phrases

I was doing [this](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/unex-esl-mooc/CommasPractice2/story.html) online quiz and came across a compound sentence. The first sentence is this:

```
The soccer team celebrated its victory *by going to Disneyland*.
```

My question is what kind of phrases is 'by going to Disneyland'. Is that a prepositional phrase? Shouldn't we need a comma before that phrase since it's just adding extra information. Any reference to grammar standards on the comma usage in relation to this type of sentence will be appreciated.

Comment: Each of "by going" and "to Disneyland" is a prepositional phrase, where the second modifies the first. The entire phrase (by going (to Disneyland)) is adverbial and tells *how* they celebrated.

Comment: Commas are restored in: "The soccer team, *by going to Disneyland,*  celebrated its victory." but it is not the natural way to say it.

Comment: It is sometimes a matter of opinion about what information in a given sentence is "extra." If we know that the team had won an important victory, it is probably safe to assume that it celebrated. The fact that the team went to Disneyland may, in other words, be the key information that this sentence provides, and so no comma is correct. Otherwise (if the adverbial phrase really is extra), a comma is technically correct, but it is not commonly used. Many popular magazines and websites these days use an em dash to separate a clause like this—a more dubious practice.